# Duration of SpaceX Demo-2 mission

Tags: iss, crewed-spaceflight, dragon-v2, planning

I've read that the duration of the current SpaceX demo mission to the ISS and back is highly variable.  It was originally estimated they could be on-board the ISS from 1 to 4 months, and [currently they're assuming a return in late July or early August](https://www.teslarati.com/spacex-crew-dragon-nasa-astronauts-return-date/).

One explanation given is that they're monitoring the degradation of the solar array, but this seems more of a we'll-stay-as-long-as-possible-unless-the-Dragon-fails-sooner-than-expected sort of a plan, rather than a more solid plan of how long to go up and stay.

It all seems very casual.  If I were planning a road trip to the next state over, the difference in planning for 1 month vs. 4 months would be very different, and I don't even have to bring my own food and life support.  The mission planning seems confusing.  Some specific questions:

- Was this mission really so broadly planned, or were there more specific but perhaps not guaranteed plans?
- Do other missions to the ISS have this much variability in their planning?
- I assume the astronauts are busy on the ISS.  How can they effectively plan the workload with such a variability in the schedule and personnel?  If they go home early, does someone's experiment simply not get done?

Comment: They doubled Christina Koch's stay after she had arrived! Things seem different these days.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Is it just the case that things are more routine, that there are ample supplies available?  Perhaps enough frequent ways to get to the ISS that not every detail needs to be planned out in detail?  Somewhat related... I did see in a documentary once an astronaut complaining that the previous crew ate up all of the good food that he was allotted, and they didn't tell anyone or the new crew could have brought up more to replenish.  I was surprised that they didn't strictly track consumables.